# Referencing to inputted table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, input

I have many tables generated automatically in separated tex files which i input in my main document using

`\input{table1}`
`\input{table2}`
...

Is it possible to refer to this table by using its name or in some other way, without going into each table1.tex (table2.tex etc...) and adding label?

Comment: Are they being generated in LaTeX form already? If so, why not have them autogenerate one more line, viz `\label{<text>}`?

Comment: You could write a custom macro which would input the file and wrap the contents in a `table` environment, adding a caption and label. But the `\label` has to get into the `table` environment after `\caption` or inside the `\caption`. That is, you could have the autogeneration generate fewer lines rather than more.

Comment: pgfplotstable might be useful here, too

Comment: you can try `\input{table1}\label{tab:label} ...\input{table2}\label{tab:label}` it can works

Comment: What is the structure of the file `table1.tex`?  Knowing that one might be able to hook in to one of the commands it contains.